# SQL Query to combine multiple rows into one based on ID while keeping other value in the same row?

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

first of all, I have been searching for this for some time.

I have a table that looks kinda like this :

```
ID        Expenditure  MonthYear
1A        1,000        122019
1A        1,500        012020
1B        1,900        122019
1C        2,400        122019
1B        2,400        012020
1C        900          012020
1A        800          022020
```

Since the rows can reach to thousands, and some IDs are repeated tens of times, I want to combine those with distinct ID into a single row and add columns which retain all the information in it. I want to make the table to looks something like this :

```
ID        Expenditure_1  MonthYear_1 Expenditure_2 MonthYear_2  Expenditure_3   MonthYear_3
1A        1,000          122019      1,500         012020       800             022020
1B        1,900          122019      2,400         012020       Null            Null
1C        2,400          122019      900           012020       Null            Null
```

What is the best way in approaching this problem using SQL on Impala?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and row_number():

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then expenditure end) as expenditure_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then monthyear end) as monthyear_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then expenditure end) as expenditure_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then monthyear end) as monthyear_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then expenditure end) as expenditure_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then monthyear end) as monthyear_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by right(monthyear, 4), left(monthyear, 2)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```